# How to make style css live reloading in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

In my angular 2 app project, 
We use app.component.html that has structure like :

```
<header>
    <div id="landing-content" style="display:none;">
       some content here
    </div>
</header>
<div class="">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Then, I have 2 file landing-page & product-page that use app.component to inheritance the layout. As expected, I want that the #landing-content div in header is displayed in landing-page, and other page isn't. 
Here is content of these file : 
file : landing-page.component.ts
...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'landingPage',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.css', './blog.css'],
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
....
```

file landing-page.component.css :

```
#landing-content {
  display : inherit !important;
}
```

File article-page.component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'articlePage',
  styleUrls: ['./article-page.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './article-page.component.html'
})
...
```

File article-page.component.css

```
#landing-content {
  display : none !important;
}
```

My problem is : If I click to the article link from landing-page redirect to page article, the #landing-content is still displayed, although I set the css for this one is display:none; This's only hidden when I refresh article page in browser. 
So that seem the css is not instantly reload in angular 2. How can I solve this problem ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to force Angular to notice the changes and refresh on its own. But if you clear your cache in your browser or do a `shift` + `refresh` on the page then that should load the new CSS.

Comment: If I refresh the page, it's hidden in article-page. But I cannot make my customer refresh all time to see the different.

Comment: I feel that, in angular 2 app , when click redirect link, that doesn't reload the web content, so that cause the share css DOM element will not changed :(

Comment: Why are you trying to hide something by updating your CSS rules? Angular's whole purpose is to build, arrange and change the page on the fly. Just make a `<div *ngIf="condition">` or `<div [hidden]="condition" >`.

Comment: I'm new in angular, that's why I created the content as I did with other framework. I will try your suggestion @JeremyThille. Can you make it more clear how to use ngIf in this case.

Comment: If by "other framework" you mean jQuery, well, forget about jQuery's way indeed :) Have a look at [ngIf's doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: OK. I should come back and read document. I'm style of coder who just try coding and search first, lol.